# Git local ignore a symlinked dir

Tags: git, git-subtree

I have two repos. They both include the same git subtree.

During development, I want to symlink one subtree dir to the other.

```
/app1
  - subtree
/app2
  - subtree -> /app1/subtree
```

When I run `git status` on `app2` I get see that `app2/subtree` and its contents have been deleted.

I want git to ignore the deleted files for the `/app2` repo.

And I want to be able to make commits to `app2` (not touching anything in `subtree`).

I tried adding `subtree/` to `.git/info/exclude` but the deleted files still show in `git status`.

I tried `git update-index --assume-unchanged subtree/` too and it also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21904084/130910) I worked out my problems were caused by:

- Not running `update-index` *before* deleting the files.
- Not using a wildcard for the files to ignore with `update-index`.

Running this before deleting the files works:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged subtree/**/*(.)
```

NOTE: The `(.)` was necessary because without it I got `fatal: Unable to mark file subtree/some-dir`. And using `**/*.*` would leave out files like `Vagrantfile`.

Use `git ls-files -v | grep '^h'` to verify which files are `assume-unchanged`.

You can add them as git aliases [here](https://coderwall.com/p/gjp15g/git-temporarily-ignoring-files).